# Very wierd undefined control sequence error, using ctuthesis class

Tags: errors, undefined, control

I'm writing a thesis at the moment and I'm using the LaTex class that my university recommends. It's called ctuthesis https://github.com/tohecz/ctuthesis. I'm also using a pacakge called gfig (https://asinus.feld.cvut.cz/geec/# -> Export -> LaTex -> Library for LaTex (gfig)), it is used for reading output files of a cuircit simulator and I have to use it. The problem is that even though I succesfully load the package, I get an Undefined control sequence error saying it doesn't recognize \gfig. It also seems wierd to me that in the .log file, this same error jumps up multiple times, even though there is only one instance of \gfig. Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{ctuthesis}

\usepackage{gfig}

\ctusetup{
    mainlanguage = czech,
    author = {Šimon Fojtík},
    month = 5,
    year = 2020
}

\ctuprocess

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\gfig{Circuit}
\end{document}
```

Now, I 
definitely think it's an error caused by the ctuthesis class, because gfig worked without a problem when I used article class. Also, I'm using TeXstudio and miktex. The creator of ctuthesis didnt respond to issues for a few years now, but I'm hoping it's something trivial and easy to fix. Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

EDIT: Here is part of the lofg file:

```
Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):
(hyperref)                removing `\ctuthesis_field_use:nn' on input line 958.



Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):
(hyperref)                removing `\ctuthesis_field_use:n' on input line 958.
.
.
.
! Undefined control sequence.
\@calc@post@scan ...st@scan \else \def \calc@next 
                                                  {\calc@error #1}\fi \fi \f...
l.18 \gfig{
           Circuit}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
\GenericError  ...                                
                                                    #4  \errhelp \@err@     ...
l.18 \gfig{
           Circuit}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
\GenericError  ...                                
                                                  \let \@err@               ...
l.18 \gfig{
           Circuit}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
\GenericError  ...                                
                                                  \@empty \def \MessageBreak...
l.18 \gfig{
           Circuit}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
\GenericError  ...                                
                                                     \endgroup 
l.18 \gfig{
           Circuit}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
.
.
.
```

Comment: The `gfig` package uses `keycommand`, which is among a set of buggy packages.

Comment: I hope that the creator of ctuthesis do repond here, becuse the user yo is active at this site:)

Comment: @wipet The problem is with `keycommand`, not with `ctuthesis`.

Comment: but why does it work with diffrent document classes? i suppose that means there isnt an easy fix?

Comment: Maybe, you can generate gfigs to pdf files with another document class and then include such pdf into ctuthesis document...

Comment: @egreg I didn't say that the bug is explicitly in ctuthesis.

Comment: @wipet ye, probably gonna have to do that :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The unrecognized control sequence is `\calc@next`; the error message ends with `\gfig`, but that's where TeX has arrived in the input file when it encountered the error.

This error is typical of situations when the `calc` package is loaded (which is done indirectly by `ctuthesis.cls`, through `pdfpages`) and `\setlength` or similar command is expanded inside `\edef`, which they don't survive when `calc` is loaded.

The `keycommand` package defines commands in a ***very*** fragile way; the author of `gfig.sty` was careful in telling `keycommand` to keep safe some commands, but didn't take into account `\setlength`, `\addtolength` and `\setcounter` that can be indeed modified by `calc`.

**Solution.** Open the `gfig.sty` file and change all occurrences of

```
\setlength    \addtolength    \setcounter
```

into

```
|\setlength|    |\addtolength|    |\setcounter|
```

You might want to test this version of `gfig.sty` that's free from the problem.

```latex
%%% gfig.sty
\RequirePackage{graphicx,xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\box_new:N \l_gfig_main_box
\dim_new:N \l_gfig_xn_dim   % natural width
\dim_new:N \l_gfig_xf_dim  % scaled or imposed width
\dim_new:N \l_gfig_yf_dim  % scaled or imposed height

\NewDocumentCommand{\gfig}{O{}m}
 {
  \group_begin:
  \keys_set:nn { gfig } { #1 }
  \gfig_main:n { #2 }
  \group_end:
 }

\keys_define:nn { gfig }
 {
  width .dim_set:N = \l_gfig_width_dim,
  width .initial:n = -1000pt,
  scale .tl_set:N = \l_gfig_scale_tl,
  scale .initial:n = 1,
  addtowidth .dim_set:N = \l_gfig_addtowidth_dim,
  addtowidth .initial:n = 0pt,
  addtoheight .dim_set:N = \l_gfig_addtoheight_dim,
  addtoheight .initial:n = 0pt,
  hshift .dim_set:N = \l_gfig_hshift_dim,
  hshift .initial:n = 0pt,
  vshift .dim_set:N = \l_gfig_vshift_dim,
  vshift .initial:n = 0pt,
  textsize .tl_set:N = \l_gfig_textsize_tl,
}

\cs_new_protected:Nn \gfig_main:n
 {
  \hbox_set:Nn \l_gfig_main_box { \includegraphics{#1} }
  \dim_set:Nn \l_gfig_xn_dim { \box_wd:N \l_gfig_main_box }
  \mbox
   {
    \dim_compare:nTF { \l_gfig_width_dim = -1000pt }
     {
      \hbox_set:Nn \l_gfig_main_box { \includegraphics[scale=\l_gfig_scale_tl]{#1} }
     }
     {
      \hbox_set:Nn \l_gfig_main_box { \includegraphics[width=\l_gfig_width_dim]{#1} }
     }
    \dim_set:Nn \l_gfig_xf_dim { \box_wd:N \l_gfig_main_box }
    \dim_set:Nn \l_gfig_yf_dim { \box_ht:N \l_gfig_main_box }
    \dim_set:Nn \unitlength { \fp_eval:n { \l_gfig_xf_dim/\l_gfig_xn_dim } in }
    \vbox_to_ht:nn { \l_gfig_yf_dim + \l_gfig_addtoheight_dim + \l_gfig_vshift_dim }
     {
      \vss
      \hbox_to_wd:nn { \l_gfig_xf_dim + \l_gfig_addtowidth_dim + \l_gfig_hshift_dim }
       {
        \skip_horizontal:n { \l_gfig_hshift_dim }
        \hbox_to_wd:nn { 0pt }
         {
          \includegraphics[width=\l_gfig_xf_dim]{#1}
          \hss
         }
        \l_gfig_textsize_tl 
        \begin{picture}(0,0)
        \input{#1.ppp}
        \end{picture}
       }
      \skip_vertical:n { \l_gfig_vshift_dim }
     }
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much, this does it flawlessly. I'll let my thesis supervisor know about this,  as I believe he is a co-author of gfig. Once again, thank you, this problem would set me quite a lot back.

Comment: @ŠimonFojtík I prepared a new version of `gfig.sty` that uses `expl3` and is much simpler. You may want to test it with diagrams you already have.

Comment: I tried it and it works well, thanks

Comment: @chips The most challenging part was the final computation of `\unitlength`. The result I get is the same as the original for the first two decimal digits (which is the accuracy of that computation), so the two versions should work the same up to essentially invisible shifts of the symbols.